# Would I be able to use a GeForce 7300SE with a new(ish) OS distribution?

Tags: windows-7, linux, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I've received a(n ostensibly working) NVIDIA GeForce 7300SE PCIe display adapter.

I know that at least as far as NVIDIA drivers go, this is a legacy card not supported by the new NVIDIA Linux kernel drivers coming out. So:

- Will I, or won't I, be able to use this card with a modern Linux distribution - for desktop uses (i.e. not gaming)?
- Same question for Windows 7/10?
- Could there be any hardware incompatibility issues with newer motherboards?

Comment: This card is probably a lot slower than any recent CPU- integrated GPU. Usable only for the additional monitor ports.

Comment: It should work as a display device, but that probably about as far as it will go. Without driver support you are not likely to get any forms of video, 2D or 3D acceleration. Have you *tried* it? What did it do? What is your *actual* problem?

Comment: @Mokubai: I've tried it, only to have the NVIDIA driver complain the card is too old and isn't supported. I've been hesitant to mess with my display setup.

Comment: @TurboJ: See edit. I'm also interested in it for a machine where the board is not so new - as it provides an additional output interface (DVI, not just VGA).

Comment: With Windows 7 you *might* be able to find some older drivers that will work, but the Windows 10 display driver model (WDDM) updates mandate minimum driver support iirc. I do not know if similar restrictions would be in place on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvidia still supports Geforce 6xxx and 7xxx https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Version_304.135_.28legacy_GPUs.29

Besides that, these older versions are supported by the default free Nvidia driver = nouveau ( nouveau.ko ) https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/